# UITableViewCell UIButton Selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, xcode8

It would be great if someone can help to achieve the below requirement.
In the tableviewcell, i have horizontal scrollview which will have uibuttons added dynamically. User can select multiple buttons from one row, but cannot select button from different rows. For e.g., If I have already selected buttons(i should be able to select one or more buttons) in row1, and when i tap button in row2, selected buttons in row1 should be deselected and the button which i tapped in row2 should be selected.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  cell.timeslotScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 0);
  cell.timeslotScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
  cell.timeslotScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

  UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 68, 35);
  [button setTitle:@"abc" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  button.layer.borderWidth = 2;
  button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.71 blue:0.29 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
  button.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
  button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.71 blue:0.29 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button setTag:indexPath.row];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
  button1.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x+68+buttonSpace, 0, 68, 35);
  [button1 setTitle:@"5 pm"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button1.layer.borderWidth = 2;
  button1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
  button1.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
  button1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [button1 setTag:indexPath.row];


  [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  [cell.timeslotScrollView addSubview:button];
  [cell.timeslotScrollView addSubview:button1];

  }

  return cell;
}

-(void)didTap:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
  if (pressedButton.tag != selectedButton ) {
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    selectedButton = pressedButton.tag;


  }
  else{
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code? If so, please post it. If not, try to solve your problem, then come back if you still can't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @CalebKleveter i have updated my question along with the code what i tried

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If I have already selected buttons(i should be able to select one or more buttons) in row1, and when i tap button in row2, selected buttons in row1 should be deselected and the button which i tapped in row2 should be selected.

Comment: Actually, the other question is a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach. I would subclass UITableViewCell and add the button inside the cell implementation file. Then I would add a method in this cell that trigger the selection/deseletion of the buttons and any other action you need to perform.

At this point, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate your only concern will be to call the method in the cell to perform the selection deselection.

Comment: Even if you subclass the uitableviewcell , you have to write button action method separately and I believe all the selection/deselection will happen in this method. So there is no much difference whether you subclass or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath] deselectAllButtons];
}
```

Now everytime a row gets unselected, all its buttons will be deselected, no matter what happens on any of the other rows. You will still have to write your own `deselectAllButtons` method, e.g. by iterating over all the subviews of `timeslotScrollView`.