# Tableviewcell button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, xcode8

I have tableview , where I subclassed tableviewcell. There is a horizontal scrollview in the cell and I add dynamic button to the scrollview.

[image]

My requirement:
1. When I tap the button(s) on row0 for the first time, I need to set a different BG color for the tapped button and add the button index in the array. When I tap the same button the second time, I need to clear the BG of the tapped button and remove the button index from the array - I'm able to achieve this
2. Let's say, I have selected two buttons in row0 and when I try to tap some button on row1, I should clear the BG color of all the selected button in row0, clear the array and set the BG color of the tapped button of row2 and add this button index in the same array - I have big problem achieving this.

In the above-attached image, I have selected "Test 0" and "Test 1" buttons in "room 1". Now when I tap "Test 0" or "Test 1" button in "room 2", I should clear all the selected buttons in "room 1" and select/set BG color of tapped button in "room 2".

// Updated code
    Mysolution:

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"roomCells";

      cell = (roomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  UIButton *slotButton;
  cell.timeslotScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 0);
  cell.timeslotScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
  cell.timeslotScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
  int buttonSpace = 10;
  int buttonWidth = 68;
  int buttonHeight = 35;
  int yPosition = 0;
  float xPosition = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<=1; i++) {
    slotButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    slotButton.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    [slotButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slotButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.71 blue:0.29 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
    slotButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    slotButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.71 blue:0.29 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    slotButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    slotButton.tag = i;

    slotButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [slotButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    xPosition = slotButton.frame.origin.x+buttonWidth+buttonSpace;

    if (cell.timeslotScrollView.subviews.count < numberOfItems)
    {
      [cell.timeslotScrollView addSubview:slotButton];
    }
  }

      }

      return cell;
    }


Updated Action method:

-(void)didTap:(id)sender
{
  static int buttonTapCount = 0;
  buttonTapCount++;
  NSMutableArray *toDelete = [NSMutableArray new];
  NSMutableArray *toAdd = [NSMutableArray new];
  UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
  CGPoint touchPoint = [pressedButton convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.roomTableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexOfButton = [self.roomTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
  NSInteger buttonIndex = pressedButton.tag;
  NSString *buttonIndexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)buttonIndex];

if (buttonTapCount==1)
{
tappedButtonRowIndex = indexOfButton.row;
[toAdd addObject:buttonIndexString];
[pressedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
else if(buttonTapCount>=1)
{
  if (tappedButtonRowIndex==indexOfButton.row)
  {
      if (buttonSelectedArray.count==0)
      {
      [toAdd addObject:buttonIndexString];
      [pressedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
      }
      else
      {
      isButtonAlreadySelected = false;
      for (NSString  *value in buttonSelectedArray)
      {
        if ([buttonIndexString isEqualToString:value])
        {
        [toDelete addObject:value];
        [pressedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        isButtonAlreadySelected = true;
        }
      }
      }
  }
  else
  {
  if (buttonSelectedArray.count==0)
      {
      [toAdd addObject:buttonIndexString];
      [pressedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
      tappedButtonRowIndex = indexOfButton.row;
      isButtonAlreadySelected=true;
      }
      else
      {
        isButtonAlreadySelected=true;

      UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"Please deselect the previous selected slots" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

      [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];

      [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show me the code of slotButton action i.e. `-didTap:` method

Comment: It's already there in my solution code section

Comment: it is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method not `didTap` method. take a look again

Comment: I'm not sure, why you are not able to see the didTap method, may be did you forgot to scroll ? Anyhow, i have again added the didTap method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell UIButton Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170247/uitableviewcell-uibutton-selection)

Comment: Is this the same question as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170247/uitableviewcell-uibutton-selection ?

Comment: Koen, yes it is. My question , solution is very clear in this post. Looking forward for the idea/solution

Comment: I tried your idea, but I couldn't achieve what I'm expecting. Can you please provide me the detailed implementation ?

Comment: Don't make new questions for the same problem. If you have additional info to add, just edit the original question. If you have a comment on an answer, add it with that answer. And "I couldn't achieve what I'm expecting" is not very helpful to understand what you are having trouble with. Please continue in the other thread.

Comment: This post has detail problem, my solution approach. Let's continue in this thread if you don't mind

Comment: @user3310076 Thats fine, then delete other post, but keep any one question post.

Comment: I'm still not able to solve point 2 in my requirement but did in different approach. Now I have one more problem, when I scroll the tableview, selected button state changes. i.e., if two buttons are selected in row0, and when i scroll, some other row's button is selected. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please update your code above with what you have accomplished and solved with your different approach.

Comment: I have updated the code